# Replace values in dataframe below a row wise threshold R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (intensities) in which I want to replace all values below a row-wise threshold  with 0. The threshold is 80% of the maximum value of the respective row. The result should be safed as a new dataframe

I tried this:

```
cutoff <- function(x){
 x[x < 0.8* max(x)] <- 0
} 

filter_int <- t(apply(X= intensities, MARGIN = 1, FUN= cutoff))
```

running this, filter_int is one row  with all zeroes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Classic problem. An R function returns the value returned by the last line. If you assign something, R invisibly returns the value you assigned. In your case, that's the `0`.

Add an explicit return statement to solve this:

```
cutoff <- function(x){
 x[x < 0.8* max(x)] <- 0
 return(x)
}
```

If you use `apply`, remember that it will return a matrix with a row for every variable in this case. So you'll have to transpose it and then return to a data frame using `data.frame()`. Since `for` loops are quite a lot optimized compared to a few years back, this is actually faster:

```
df <- as.data.frame(
  replicate(10, sample(1:100,100))
)

df2 <- df
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
  df2[i,] <- cutoff(df[i,])
}
```

Comment: thanks, now it works